# Return value from promise in another promise

Tags: javascript, promise

There are quit a lot of questions about how to return value from promises, but I don't see any that answers my question.

this is my function:

```
function f1(arr, num) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(data);
    }).then(function(data){
        f2.then(function(d){
            // how to return d 
        }).catch(...);

        function f2(data){
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                data = data + 1
                resolve (data);
            });
        };
    })
    .catch(function(){...});
}
```

How can I return `d` in this configuration ?

Comment: You can't. You don't return from a callback. You give that callback another callback, then pass `d` to the other callback and use it there. When using callbacks, you must rely on side effects. This will slowly dissolve into "callback hell" though, so be careful.

Comment: "Return `d`" *to whom/where*?

Comment: Here, by "slowly", @Carcigenicate means "immediately".

Comment: @DaveNewton Well, depending on how you've set everything up, you may not get bitten immediately. I managed to write a website from scratch without any libraries for a CS class without it achieving what could be considered "hell", and I relied heavily on callbacks to do my async module loading. I know heavy use of callbacks is bad, but I haven't personally seen the worst effects of it for myself. I guess I lucked out.

Comment: It should be noted that I read the question very poorly (my bad). If you were "manually" managing callbacks, then you can't return from them since the calling code has already moved on. If using promises though, you can return since the calling code has a "handle" to receive values from. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Carcigenicate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
function f1(arr, num) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(data);
    }).then(function(data){
        return f2(data).then(function(d){
//      ^^^^^^ don't forget this
//               ^^^^^^ call the function
            return d;
//          ^^^^^^^^^ simply and literally return d 
        }).catch(...);

        function f2(data){
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                data = data + 1
                resolve (data);
            });
        };
    })
    .catch(function(){...});
}
```

or written better as

```
function f1(arr, num) {
    return Promise.resolve(data)
    .then(f2)
    .catch(function(){...});
}

function f2(data){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        … // do some async work
        resolve(data + 1);
    });
}
```